# Best way to store large tables that require sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a very large table in which :
Rows are the different material sections (need to chose between rows).
Columns are the different properties of my sections.

I need to be able to sort every kind of property (column) in order to decide which section (row) is best for my design. What would be the best way to do this?

I started out with a dictionnary that had the column name as key and the whole column as value. This allowed me to subdivide my propreties, but not to sort them.

I then moved on to tuples, which seem to makes sense. Every section would has the same propreties, so i could make every row into a tuple. I'm not sure how I could then sort the tuples to find the best suiting section though.

Maybe I ought to only use list of lists, or numpy? I'm looking for the "good" way to code this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you use a relational database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted something simple, and wanted to stick with your tuple-of-tuples (or any iterable-of-iterables), you can use the `key` property of the built-in [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).
For example, to sort by index 1 of each tuple, you could do this:

```
>>> data = ((1,9), (1,2), (2,8), (2,4))
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda x : x[1])
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (2, 8), (1, 9)]
```